# Javascript jquery animate, toggling, doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle, jquery-animate

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
                #tempc {
                    background-color: #FFFF00;
                    width: 50px;
                    height: 50px;
                }
        </style>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function toggle(){
                $("#tempc").toggle(
                    function () {
                        $("#tempc").animate({width: 255, height: 300}, 1000, "easeInOutQuad")
                    },
                    function () {
                        $("#tempc").animate({width: 50}, 1000, "easeInOutQuad")
                    }
                );
            }
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="tempc" onclick="toggle();">
            Hello!
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Hello Stackoverflow,
I try to use toggle to switch in animate functions, but the code showen above doesn't seem to work? What is wrong?

Greetings

Comment: The jQuery "toggle" function is for setting up handlers that respond to alternate clicks.  This code looks like it's trying to set up those handlers after an element is clicked. Is that what you want?

Comment: @Pointy, no! `hover(fn, fn)` do that.

Comment: Also, you need to import jQuery UI in order to get that fancy easing method.

Comment: @Cybrix oh you're right, thanks; I'll edit my comment ...

Comment: @Pointy Haha, it was jQuery UI that i forgot, thanks =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
<body>

        <div id="tempc" onclick="toggle();">
```

To this:

```
<body onload="toggle();">

    <div id="tempc">
```

**[DEMO - except for easing](http://jsfiddle.net/ZB9SD/)**

Comment: When using jQuery it really isn't necessary to put onload in the body tag. Much better to use $().ready(). It's simpler and keeps the HTML and JavaScript separate.

Answer (score 1):

Setup toggle handler on **pageload** using jquery **ready** function. Remove onclick handler from div. Check this [code](http://jsfiddle.net/s66Km/).

```
$(function (){
    $("#tempc").toggle(
        function () {
            $("#tempc").animate({width: 255, height: 300}, 1000);
        },
        function () {
            $("#tempc").animate({width: 50}, 1000);
        }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
                #tempc {
                    background-color: #FFFF00;
                    width: 50px;
                    height: 50px;
                }
        </style>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="tempc">
            Hello!
        </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $().ready(function(){
        $('#tempc').toggle(
            function(){
            $(this).animate({width: 255, height: 300}, 1000, 'linear')
                    },
                    function () {
                        $(this).animate({width: 50}, 1000, 'linear')
                    }
        );
        });
    </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

The `onclick` handler has been removed from the `div` because it's unnecessary when using jQuery.

Also, the instances of `$('#tempc')` in the callbacks has been changed to `$(this)`. This is the "correct" way of doing things and I believe this is more efficient for the Javascript engine (correct me if I'm wrong!).

Also, you were trying to use the `"easeInOutQuad"` function as the easing function. According to the jQuery docs, the only built-in functions that are supported are `swing` and `linear`:

> **Easing**:
>   The remaining parameter of .animate()
>   is a string naming an easing function
>   to use. An easing function specifies
>   the speed at which the animation
>   progresses at different points within
>   the animation. The only easing
>   implementations in the jQuery library
>   are the default, called swing, and one
>   that progresses at a constant pace,
>   called linear. More easing functions
>   are available with the use of
>   plug-ins, most notably the jQuery UI
>   suite.

See the jQuery docs for more info: [jQuery Animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)